# Arduino coding issue, det not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino

Hi so I am having issues compiling my code as I keep receiving an error report saying det not declared in this scope, I'm not too sure as to what the issue is but it is driving me up the walls. Any help would be appreciated I will also include the code below and if possible an image of the issue and the line it is affecting.

```
// old line: #include <NewSoftSerial.h>   //Software Serial Port
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>               //new line
#define RxD 3
#define TxD 2

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1

// old line: NewSoftSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);
SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);  //new line

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(38400);
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
  setupBlueToothConnection();

} 

void loop() 
{ 
  char(det = check)
    while(1){
      if(blueToothSerial.available()){//check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
        (det = check) = blueToothSerial.read();
        Serial.print(det = check);
      }
      if(Serial.available()){//check if there's any data sent from the local serial terminal, you can add the other applications here
        (det = check)  = Serial.read();
        blueToothSerial.print(det = check);
      }
    }
} 

void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
  blueToothSerial.begin(38400); //Set BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=SeeedBTSlave\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
  Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  blueToothSerial.flush();
}

char dataIn = 'S';       //CharacterData coming from the phone.
int pinLeftTrackFB = 13;    //Pin controls left track bank forward and backward.
int pinRightTrackFB = 14;   //Pin controls right track bank forward and backward.
int BrakeLeftTrackFB = 8;   //Pin that enables/disables the left track bank.
int BrakeRightTrackFB = 15;  //Pin that enables/disables the right track bank
int pinLeftRightSpeed = 3;   //Pin that sets the speed for the Left-Right motor.
int pinLeftTrackSpeed = 11;   //Pin that sets the speed for the Left track bank.
int pinRightTrackSpeed = 16;  //Pin that sets the speed for the Right track bank.
int pinBrakeLeftTrackFB = 1;  //Pin that brakes left track.
int pinBrakeRightTrackFB = 2;  //Pin that brakes right track.
int pincamerapower = 4;    //Pin that activates power to front camera.
int pinlights = 7;   //Pin turns on led’s around tank.
char determinant;    //Used in the check function, stores the character received from the phone.
char det;    //Used in the loop function, stores the character received from the phone.
int velocity = 0;    //Stores the speed based on the character sent by phone.

{
  //  NOTE: Once Bluetooth module is received find the Bluetooth unit number and put it in brackets of serial begin.
  Serial.begin(38400);   //Initialize serial communication with Bluetooth module at underlined number btu.
  pinMode(pinLeftTrackFB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinRightTrackFB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinBrakeLeftTrackFB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinBrakeRightTrackFB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinLeftRightSpeed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinLeftTrackSpeed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinRightTrackSpeed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pincamerapower, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinlights, OUTPUT);
}

{
  det = check();
  while (det == 'F')  //If incoming data is an F, denotes the function move forward
  {
    digitalWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinRightTrackFB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeLeftTrackFB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeRightTrackFB, LOW);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackSpeed,255);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackSpeed,255);
    det = check();
  }
  while (det == 'B')   //if incoming data is a B, move back
  {    
    digitalWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinRightTrackFB, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeLeftTrackFB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeRightTrackFB, LOW);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackSpeed,-255);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackSpeed,-255);
    det = check();          
  } 

  while (det == 'L')   //if incoming data is a L, move wheels left
  {     
    digitalWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinRightTrackFB, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeLeftTrackFB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeRightTrackFB, LOW);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackSpeed,0);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackSpeed,255);
    det = check();          
  }  
  while (det == 'R')   //if incoming data is a R, move tank right
  {    
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeLeftTrackFB,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinBrakeRightTrackFB,LOW);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackFB, velocity);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackSpeed,255);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackSpeed,0);
    det=check();
  }
  while (det == 'S')  //if incoming data is a S, stop
  {
    digitalWrite(pinLeftTrackFB, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinRightTrackFB, LOW);
    analogWrite(pinLeftTrackSpeed,0);
    analogWrite(pinRightTrackSpeed,0);
    det = check();
  }
}

int check()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)    //Check for data on the serial lines.
  {
    dataIn = Serial.read();  //Get the character sent by the phone and store it in 'dataIn'.
    if (dataIn == 'F')
    {     
      determinant = 'F';
    }  
    else if (dataIn == 'B')
    { 
      determinant = 'B'; 
    }
    else if (dataIn == 'L')  
    { 
      determinant = 'L';
    }
    else if (dataIn == 'R')  
    { 
      determinant = 'R';
    } 
    else if (dataIn == 'I')  
    { 
      determinant = 'I'; 
    }  
    else if (dataIn == 'J')  
    {  
      determinant = 'J';
    }          
    else if (dataIn == 'G') 
    {
      determinant = 'G'; 
    }    
    else if (dataIn == 'H')  
    {
      determinant = 'H'; 
    }   
    else if (dataIn == 'S') 
    {
      determinant = 'S';
    }
    else if (dataIn == '0') 
    {
      velocity = 0;    //"velocity" does not need to be returned.
    }
    else if (dataIn == '1') 
    {
      velocity = 25;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '2') 
    {
      velocity = 50;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '3') 
    {
      velocity = 75;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '4') 
    {
      velocity = 100;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '5') 
    {
      velocity = 125;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '6') 
    {
      velocity = 150;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '7') 
    {
      velocity = 175;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '8') 
    {
      velocity = 200;
    }
    else if (dataIn == '9') 
    {
      velocity = 225;
    }
    else if (dataIn == 'q') 
    {
      velocity = 255;
    }
    else if (dataIn == 'U') 
    {
      determinant = 'U';
    }
    else if (dataIn == 'u') 
    {
      determinant = 'u';
    }
    else if (dataIn == 'W') 
    {
      determinant = 'W';
    }

    else if (dataIn == 'w') 
    {
      determinant = 'w';
    }
  }
  return determinant;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the full error output and narrow down where it might be occurring in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have this line:

```
  char(det = check)
```

which has the obvious problems of not being a correct function call or variable declaration.'

You also define `det` as a global variable later in your code, after referencing it earlier

```
  char det; //Used in the loop function, stores the character received from the phone.
```

So there are three problems:

1. move the `det` declaration earlier (before `loop()`
2. don't redefine it as a local var in the `loop()` function (unless you intend that, in which case remove th global declaration)
3. use the correct format for a function call: `det = check();`

The Arduino IDE is primitive but it does provide meaningful error messages and line numbers indicating where an error occurs. Not always accurate with complex errors but a god starting point which should not be ignored.